# JSLint: Use a named parameter

Tags: jquery, jslint

So I'm running JSLint on the lastest version of jQuery available at [bit.ly/jqsource](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js). I've made the tests as lax as possible, but I still get errors. One of them is "Use a named parameter" on line 327:

`target = arguments[0] || {},`

What does it mean? Even [this blog post](http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2011/01/17/jslint-a-guide-to-jslint-messages/) doens't provide information.

Comment: It sounds like it's upset about `arguments[0]` -- is there a reason you cannot accept a proper named parameter?  I have a suspicion that JSLint would have no problem if the index was not a constant.

Comment: @cdhowie Isn't this being ran on jQuery though? :P

Comment: @alex: It does not matter.  If you are referencing `arguments` with a *constant* index then you could just as easily define a named parameter and use it instead.  (That's what JSLint is saying, anyway.)

Comment: @cdhowie: They mean that OP is running the jQuery *source* through JSLint.

Comment: @patrick: And apparently JSLint has found something that could be corrected.  ;)

Comment: @cdhowie: http://bugs.jquery.com ;)

Comment: @patrick: ... Why is the onus on me to report a JSLint error found by someone else?

Comment: Since `jQuery.extend` expects a variable number of parameters by design, what's a better option than using `arguments` directly?

Comment: @cdhowie: Because I said. Now go to your room, and don't come out until jQuery is fully JSLint compliant.

Comment: @orip: In the next version of ECMAScript, we'll likely be able to do `function my_func(first,...rest){ other_func.apply(null,...rest); }`, which means that in about 10 years, we'll actually be able to use it in a browser! Woo hoo!

Comment: @orip: It could easily be written to use names for the first two arguments (even though they are optional).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that the code is accessing the parameter using the `arguments` collection instead of a parameter specified in the function signature:

You can reproduce the error message with this code:

```
function x(a) {
    var b = arguments[0];
}
```

Using the named parameter gives the same result without the lint error:

```
function x(a) {
    var b = a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume it actually says *"Use a named parameter"* instead of *"variable"*.

If so, there can be a performance hit in some browsers when you reference the `arguments` object. I'd guess that's what it's complaining about.

Some browsers will optimize away the creation of the `arguments` object if it is never referenced.